# New keyboard shortcut in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, keyboard, shortcut

You probably know that if you highlight text with cursor, and push Ctrl+B, you can get

```
\textbf{highlighted text}
```

instead of what was before:

```
highlighted text
```

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut similarly for the following:

```
\colorbox{pink}{highlighted text}
```

I am using TeXStudio.

Comment: Are TeXstudio's macros described in my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest thing you can do is to set up a macro (`Macros`>`Edit Macros...`).

You can either select one of several keyboard shortcuts (here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>),
or an abbreviation that, when you type it like a regular command, shows up in the auto-completion window marked with '(Usertag)'.

Highlighted text will be inserted at the marker for curser position `%|`.

[image]

[image]